# get signal name from signal number in PHP

Tags: php, signals

Lets say I have a signal number, let's say it is `15`, how can I get that back to a signal name? (on Linux, 15 is SIGTERM, so in this case if running on Linux, I would like the string "SIGTERM")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux has [char *strsignal(int sig)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strsignal), unfortunately seems like PHP doesn't, but with `get_defined_constants(true)`, one could probably implement something similar, here is my attempt:

```
function strsignal(int $signo): ?string
{
    foreach (get_defined_constants(true)['pcntl'] as $name => $num) {
        // the _ is to ignore SIG_IGN and SIG_DFL and SIG_ERR and SIG_BLOCK and SIG_UNBLOCK and SIG_SETMARK, and maybe more, who knows
        if ($num === $signo && substr($name, 0, 3) === "SIG" && $name[3] !== "_") {
            return $name;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

and `var_dump(strsignal(15));` returns `string(7) "SIGTERM"`

:)

- made a request for posix_strsignal() in php upstream here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=78700

Answer (score 0):

Getting signal names from get_defined_constants() like the accepted answer, but without the foreach and single liner:

```
$signum=15;
$signal_name=array_search($signum, array_filter(get_defined_constants(true)['pcntl'], fn($name)=>preg_match("/^SIG[A-Z]/",$name), ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY), true);
var_dump($signal_name);
```

The `get_defined_constants(true)['pcntl']` returns an array with all the pcntl constant names and relative values. The array is filtered with `array_filter()` through a callback arrow function which in turns filters data using `preg_match()` who returns only the strings starting with SIG followed by capital letters only. This clean array can be finally searched for its values by `array_search()`.

Or you could filter the array value directly into the array_filter():

```
$signum=15;
$signal_name=current(array_flip(array_filter(get_defined_constants(true)['pcntl'], function($value,$name) use ($signum) {return (($value==$signum)&&preg_match("/^SIG[A-Z]/",$name));}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH)));
var_dump($signal_name);
```

Comment: This doesn't offer the performance benefits of an early return like the earlier answer's loop has.  This answer will unconditionally iterate the full array.  Why not check for `15` within `array_filter()` and avoid the extra loop?

Comment: @mickmackusa the performance is negligible because the array is really small and the search is running in native code (internal PHP functions). Anyway, pls check this one that filters the array internally into the closure: $signal_name=current(array_flip(array_filter(get_defined_constants(true)['pcntl'], function($value,$name) use ($signum) {return (preg_match("/^SIG[A-Z]/",$name)&&($value==$signum));}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH)));

Comment: Modern, PSR-12 compliant version of your snippet: https://3v4l.org/Mk9F4

Comment: @mickmackusa if you think this stuff is better than a simple foreach, you're both crazy. anyway, checking the number before the string is actually about performance, running `int === int` is super fast, so i suggest you do `$value == $signum` before invoking preg_  - in PHP8.2.10, this will avoid about 122x invocations of preg_ for $signum=15.